# Cakephp 3 hasMany associations a lot of queries

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Videos.hasMany Comments and Comments.belongsTo Videos

so when i do

```
/*Select video by id*/   
 $videos = $this->Videos
    ->findById($videoId)
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->contain(['Comments']);
```

i end up with 23 select query instead of 2.

```
SELECT * FROM videos;
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE video_id IN (1) ;
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE video_id IN (1) ;
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE video_id IN (1) ;
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE video_id IN (1).... ;

is there anyway to execute only 2 queries,Am i doing something wrong ?
```

Fix:
I restarted the server and it's fixed, it was debug kit problem.

Comment: Are you sure these are the queries executed? I mean shouldn't there be a where statement on videos according to your php code.